# How to enable split pane visual preview in IntelliJ 14 when viewing xml text

Tags: android, intellij-idea

First time I double clicked on the layout main.xml file in an Android project, it brought me to the text view, but there was also a visual preview (in the right side of the view). I clicked on the arrow to hide the visual preview.

Now how do I get this preview back?

(Yes there is the Design tab , but initially there was a visual view in the *text* section aswell!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find it in the left bottom corner like the image below.[image]